# Different browsers render my website fonts in different ways

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using font *Avenir Black* for one of my buttons on a web page. But Chrome & Microsoft Edge shows it differently.

Even I have cleared the cache of both & inspected the web page in both browsers there is no error in the console and the font is Avenir Black.

Anybody knows the reason? I have attached the snapshot of the outputs along with the code.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve], DON'T post your code as image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are just using one format (ttf) for your desired typeface and not all the web browsers can read that. You can read this article for more info. Then you will figure out how to fix this in a very easy way!

But there is no single font format that is supported in all browsers and browser versions. TTF and WOFF file formats are supported in nearly all latest web browsers (except opera mini). As a developer it would make your life quite easier if you use TTF and WOFF web formats. But still, you would need to have a combinations of font formats to make all the fonts supported in all browsers.

[Typography And Cross Browser Compatibility](https://medium.com/@sarahelson81/typography-and-cross-browser-compatibility-fc1fa3b8fa9a)